# 2-dimensional arrays in ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Long story short, i'm looking for a way to create and fill 2D arrays using ES6, in an effort to avoid `for` loops. The created array should contain all 0s. I've tried many different approaches so i cant post all of them.

```
var [r, c] = [5, 5]; 
var m = Array(r).fill(Array(c).fill(0));
```

This works but it creates a bunch of instances of the same array, and adding slice `Array(r).fill(Array(c).fill(0).slice());` doesn't help either.

I also tried creating the empty arrays and then looping trough them but that's a whole different problem, you apparently can't `forEach()` or `map()` an empty array, and i couldn't even loop through a filled one efficiently.

Am i missing something here? Are a whole lot of for loops the best way to approach this? It looks really messy and overly long. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Doing this worked for me:

```
var [r, c] = [5, 5]; 
var m = Array(r).fill().map(()=>Array(c).fill(0));
```

Basically just filling it with a dummy value so you can map over it

Comment: save a byte, `.fill()` :p

Comment: This one works and seems to be the fastest so far. For loops are twice as fast though, but i guess thats not what i asked, thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Array.from` that takes a callback function and inside return arrays with `0`'s using `fill` method.

```js
const arr = Array.from(Array(2), () => Array(5).fill(0))
console.log(arr)
```

Or you could just create array where each element is number of elements in sub-array and then use `map` and `fill` methods.

```js
const arr = [5, 5].map(e => Array(e).fill(0))
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: that second code is not right - it produces  2 x 5 array instead of 5 x 5

Comment: both of them do

Comment: The question asks for 5 x 5 ... your second code has `[5,5]` like the question ... but produces 2 x 5

Comment: @zevee - yes, they both do .. but it's obvious because he's hardcoded 2 and 5 in the first answer ... problem is, the question asks for 5 x 5

Comment: Personally, I would use `Array.from(Array(r), () => Array(c).fill(0));` method as it, to me looks more obvious as to its intent

Comment: Thanks for your answer, first one is looking good, although i dont think the other one works.

Answer (score 3):

For those needing the same thing but with `undefined` as each value this also works.

```js
const x = 100;
const y = 100;
const grid = [...new Array(x)].map(() => [...new Array(y)]);
```

To fill the array simply map the inner value.
This will make an array filled with `0` for each value.

```js
const x = 100;
const y = 100;
const grid = [...new Array(10)].map(() => [...new Array(10)].map(() => 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const nthArray = (n) => Array.from(Array(n), () => Array(5).fill(0))

const arr = nthArray(3);

console.log(arr);
```